# Inline [tag:foo] syntax causes lines to exceed \baselineskip

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

For example, this text is off:

> Sometimes people use [brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brackets) instead of this tag, though that can also refer to the delimeter pairs `[]` (in the U.S.) and `()` (in Britain), or even to any paired delimiters of this type. (We hopefully know better than to include `` among their number in these parts; as such usage is generally a corruption of `\langle` and `\rangle`, yes?)

Hmm. And is `<blockquote>` *supposed* to nullify the backticks-for-code markdown? Because, well, it is doing that, and the Bird-feet (originally [named after Richard Bird](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Literate_programming#Bird_Style)) (well, Bird foot) aren't (isn't).

> Sometimes people use [brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brackets) instead of this tag, though that can also refer to the delimeter pairs `[]` (in the U.S.) and `()` (in Britain), or even to any paired delimiters of this type. (We hopefully know better than to include `<>` among their number in these parts; as such usage is generally a corruption of `\langle` and `\rangle`, yes?)

Anyway, the obligatory screenshot, with the obligatory freehanding (that arrow on the left):
[image]

### Note for the Uninitiated

In TeX, `\baselineskip` is the vertical distance that is supposed to separate one baseline from the next. That is, TeX tries to make the baseline of each box (normally a line of text) added to a "vertical list" (typically "the page") exactly this distance below the baseline of the previous one; however, if this would leave the top edge of the new box within `\lineskiplimit` of the bottom edge of the previous box, `\lineskip` of "glue" (potentially-stretchable space) is used to separate them instead.

In other words, I believe that the "brackets" box is "too tall"; in this case, the problem seen is actually caused by what TeXnicians call the "depth" of the box (it extends too far down). Curiously, the analogous problem with the "height" (how high the box extends above the baseline) does not occur here: for example, [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

This problem occurs on other sites, too, but naturally, this is almost certainly the most typographically nit-picky of the bunch, and the headquarters of the whitespace police. (Also, SO's design, for example, might *need* that size of box, since the box is itself is visible there; we just have a couple of curly braces and a different font!)

### Further Details

Taking a closer look in firebug, it looks like the value of the CSS "margin-bottom" property for the element in question is too large (6) due to a ".post-tag" rule; the same problem does not occur with the line above because the value of the "margin-top" property (2) is just small enough not to matter. (The distance marked "too big" above being exactly 4 pixels more than the normal distance.)

Perhaps inline tags should belong to a different (additional?) CSS class?

Comment: I'm looking into this now. Thanks for the comprehensive write up.

Comment: +1 for calling it `\baselineskip`

Comment: Has the CSS been fixed since this was reported?

Comment: @N.N.: Well, considering that I don't see this glitch in the *text* of my question, only the screenshot, I think the answer is "yes". (Though for all *I* know, that's happened in the 10 hours since you asked this.)

Comment: @SamB So this can be considered as fixed?

Comment: @N.N.: Sure seems so, though I haven't checked on anything but Chrome under Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue seems now to be fixed.

According to the OP the issue seems to be fixed when browsing with Chrome under Windows. I can neither see the reported problem with Firefox 10.0 or Chromium 16.0.912.77 in Ubuntu.